# Simple approval process in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: content-approval

I need to have a very simple content approval process on a document library. No workflows just content approval enabled. So I have enabled it at the library.
Then I wanted to grant approval permissions to an AD group but did not find the out of the box approval sharepoint group to add them to - then I found out that this requires the publishing feature enabled.

So I created a new permission level, checked the box for approve items and granted the AD group this permission level.

When I (site collection admin) or my colleague (design permissions) go to the library we see the ability to approve/reject items so we know content approval is enabled. But when a member of the AD group goes to the library they see no content approval on the ribbon or the item drop down.

Have I missed something? I read that you can give users "edit" permissions in order for them to be able to approve/reject but I think this is overkill and do not want users editing list columns etc.