# All SharePoint 2010 "approval process" failed on start

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have tried OOTB approval workflow, as well as a custom list workflow (using Approval process action). Both failed on start immediately. Every time the error pattern is the same:
Status immediately become "Failed on start". The first workflow history is "xxxx was canceled by system account".

I tested run a workflow without Approval process (e.g. log in history) and completed successfully.

I created a new site collection and create a new SP2010 approval workflow, it failed in the same way.

What could be the reason?

Comment: What is the error when workflow gets suspended?

Comment: canceled by system account

Comment: I tried to dig in ULS log but I am unable to find anything unusal with keyword "workflow"

Answer (score 0):

It's so frustrating when workflows just don't work, so I feel compelled to suggest something.  You mentioned that your test workflow worked ok, then you set up a new site collection.  That leads me to think of Site Features - perhaps you need to activate a feature on your new site collection?

Have a look at [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163575/simple-approval-process-in-sharepoint-2013) and perhaps also this second post which discusses the [difference between types of sites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204506/whats-the-difference-between-team-sites-and-a-publishing-sites/204507#204507).  It could give you the clue you need to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to troubleshoot as following:

1. Deactivate and re-activate the Workflows feature in Site collection features and check again.
2. [Clear SharePoint Designer Cache and check again.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33469.how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache.aspx)
3. What’s the account you use to publish the workflow, try to use anther non system account and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Later I found below error message in Web front end ULS log:

> System.CodeDom.CodeBinaryOperatorExpression is not marked as
>   authorized in the application configuration file.

Then I fixed the error by adding new lines in web.config according to [MS article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update).

For SharePoint 2013 and later versions, add lines under the following tree:

```
<configuration>
<System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowCompiler>
<authorizedTypes>
<targetFx>
```

add below lines:

```
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeBinaryOperatorExpression" Authorized="True" /> 

<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodePrimitiveExpression" Authorized="True" /> 

<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeMethodInvokeExpression" Authorized="True" />

<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeMethodReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />

<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeFieldReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />

<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeThisReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />

<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodePropertyReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />
```